# Can I pass an alternative return link to an MVC controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC5 application which has several controllers, scaffolded with EF6 CRUD actions and associated views. One of these controller/view sets is used for managing a table of patient identifiers, and on completion of an edit or delete, the controller returns an action link to the identifiers index view, as expected.

However, the patient identifiers are also displayed on the various views of the patients controller, and from the Patient.Edit view I have Html.ActionLink calls to the identifier controller's edit or delete actions. When the latter are called from the Patient.Edit view, I would like them to return to that on completion.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but this is always a manual process. There's nothing built into MVC specifically for return URLs.

Essentially, your links to edit/delete will need to include a GET param, usually called `returnUrl`, though the name doesn't matter, which will be set to the current page URL. For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", new { id = patient.Id, returnUrl = Request.RawUrl })
```

Then, your edit/delete GET action should accept this parameter, and set a `ViewBag` member:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

In your edit form, add a hidden field:

```
@Html.Hidden("returnUrl", ViewBag.ReturnUrl)
```

In your POST edit action, again, accept the param:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Patient model, string returnUrl = null)
```

But inside this action is where you'll do something different now. Typically, when you've got a successful post and have saved the object or whatever, you then do something like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

However, instead, you should now check to see if `returnUrl` has a value, and if it does, redirect to that instead:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

The MVC5 with Identity sample project has a nice helper method that it uses:

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
 }
```

That would just go into your controller and basically does the same as I've already described with two notable differences:

1. It uses `Url.IsLocalUrl` to check that the return url is actually a URL on this site. That's a smart check, as since this is initially passed in the query string of the URL, it's open to be manipulated by a user.
2. It encapsulates the logic, so you don't have to remember how to this should be handled. When you have a successful POST, you simply return `RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)`, and if there's a return URL set, it will be used. Otherwise, the fallback redirect will used.

Comment: You don't need the hidden field, you can get the value from the `Request.Params` collection.

Comment: Not on POST. Unless you continue to pass it, it won't be in the request anymore. Now, in truth, if your form has `action=""` it will post to the URL *with* the `returnUrl` in the querystring still, but that's a little too "magical" for my tastes. It's not obvious why it works, and if you later need to change where the form posts to, the return URL functionality will inexplicably break with no indication as to why. By including the hidden field, you're good no matter where the form posts to.

Comment: Thanks Chris for a very comprehensive and well explained answer. I'll post some feedback when I've had a chance to try it out.

Comment: @ChrisPratt,  Thanks again Chris. I have just tried this out and it works just as I hoped. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in one of my projects:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string returnUrl)
{
    // find the model (code not shown)
    return View(model);
}
```

In the `Edit` view you don't need to do anything special, in the Post Action you have

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // save Model...    

        return Redirect(Request.Params["returnUrl"]);
        // Request.Query will work as well since it is in the querystring
        // of course you should check and validate it as well...
    }
    // else return the View as usual, not shown
}
```

To use it, when creating the "Edit" link from your pages you simply need to specify the extra `returnUrl` parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit",
    new { controller = "YourController", 
          returnUrl = Url.Action("Index", "ThisController",) 
        })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should use `Request.RawUrl` instead of `Url.Action`. If there's any querystring on the current URL, you'll lose it, and as a result you won't actually return the user to where they truly were.

Comment: Thanks Chris. A very comprehensive answer. I"m away from my dev machine for a few days, but will try this out next week and post some feedback then.